# HTML title tag not showing on website

Tags: html

I have my index.php page with a php include of `settings.php` right at the top and then under this, standard HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

in `settings.php` i have this script included:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The page title is not showing, however if i remove th jquery file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

the title shows fine, no problem.

If i check the source code of the website, the title tag shows fine too but its just not displaying when the jquery file is included

Comment: Make sure to either output the `script` within the `head` or the `body`. Otherwise your browser might have troubles determine where the *real* `head` is. Your markup would be messed up too.

Comment: Please paste you input - PHP source code, and output - HTML code

Comment: sure check this http://pastebin.com/wazMVGGA

Comment: You have included two differetn types of jQuery (1.11.2 and 2.1.3)? Aren't there any collisions with this?

Comment: 2.1.3 is not actually being included - its been commented out

Comment: I tested on Firefox and Chromium (both LInux) and I can't reproduce your problem. Is this only in some browser, or you have tis issue everywhere?

Comment: no its happening on all browsers (firefox, chrome, IE)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84310/discussion-between-areim-and-charlie).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery script should be in and at the bottom of your `<head>` or in your `<body>` not before your `<html>` element. That will create issues beyond your no title.

Try putting your `settings.php` include at the bottom of your `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

The script, and thus the `<?php include('...') ?>` should be inside your `head` element.
Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <?php include ('settings.php') ?>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: i just moved all the code out of settings.php and put it below the `<title>` tag but its still not showing

Comment: Do you have minimal example where it is not working? Could you poste e.g. JSFiddle?

Comment: For me it is working, even without my answer.  
Also, coud you please check if you have any errors in your console?